# Installing SymJava/Java Operator Overloading support in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, operator-overloading, sympy, intellij-plugin

For my project I want to use [SymJava](https://github.com/yuemingl/SymJava). The README there requires me to install the [Java Operator Overloading support](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo). Since I am using Intellij IDEA (Version 2019.1.2), I tried to follow the [directive](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo#IDEA) given. However, I am confused by the second step:

> 2. Add javac8-oo-plugin.jar as compile or processor library.

What is meant by **"compile or processor library"**?

Also a note: I did the first step before. This made Intellij IDEA ask me to restart the IDE. When I did that, a **fatal error** initializing the plugin occured when re-opening the IDE and my project:

[image]

What may be my misunderstanding in the process? I am using Java 15.0.1 here. Is that the problem perhaps, since it says something about using Java 8? I assumed it should work with later versions nevertheless.

Since I need to use this newer Java version, is it impossible for me to use SymJava then? And if so, can you recommend an **alternative library** similar to this (which is a Java counterpart to SymPy)?

Comment: Alternative lib: https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library - Here is the `Compile` function description: https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/blob/master/symja_android_library/doc/functions/Compile.md - Also see wiki section.

Comment: @axelclk Thank you, I already considered your library already (and wrote into the chat) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Add javac8-oo-plugin.jar as compile or processor library.

Means that you need to add this jar to the module classpath by adding it as a [module library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html#module-libraries). This will add it to compile classpath and to processor path if you have the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors |  | **Obtain processors from project classpath option** enabled.

> a fatal error initializing the plugin occured when re-opening the IDE and my project:

Double check the plugin zip archive file is not corrupted and is compatible with this IDE version. Btw I was unable to download it from github from the README instrucitons. You may need to better contact the repository author about this.

Comment: The steps provided by you did the job perfectly. I also noticed that my IDE version was slightly outdated, so an update solved the issue with the fatal error. When you say you were "unable to download", you mean you didn't find any instruction on how to use the SymJava library itself, am I correct? I faced the same problem (and thought I was just blind), so I contacted the author now. I will place an edit here if I get any answer!

Comment: I found a version: https://github.com/yuemingl/SymJava/releases/tag/1.1.2 Though, if I try the given examples, it says "Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'symjava.symbolic.Symbol', 'symjava.symbolic.Symbol'" for the * operator (same for +). Compiling leads to: "java: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25 cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25 is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2ff4acd0; com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app')"

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to the conclusion that SymJava is not suitable for any Java version above Java 8. This is, because SymJava uses the ["java-oo" library](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo). Since java-oo [only supports Java 8](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo/issues/67), it's not possible to use SymJava, either.

The current solution is to use a different library, like [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library), which contains similar features while also supporting Java versions later than Java 8.